# Using R to choose files from excel

Tags: r, excel

I've been trying to import excel files into R....using the choose file function

```
mydata=read.csv(file.choose())
```

or

```
myFile <- file.choose()
myData  <- read.table(myFile,header=TRUE)
```

but I get the same error

```
Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled
```

I'm using R version 2.15.3

How do I fix this? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: By `excel` files do you mean comma (or tab) separated files or `.xls` / `.xlsx` files?

Comment: Are you clicking on Cancel, rather than Open? That's the only way you'll get what's shown above.

Comment: @ALL:  Why not wait for a response before voting to close this??

Comment: The error message in the linked question is different. Why has this question been closed?

Answer (score 1):

I can get the error you indicate

```
Error in file.choose() : file choice cancelled
```

only by hitting <kbd>Cancel</kbd> on the file dialog box. If I select a file and hit <kbd>Open</kbd>, it works as intended (R-3.0.1).

Also, "Excel file" is not well defined. Do you mean a `.csv` file saved from Excel? An `.xls` file? An `.xlsx` file? Each of these is a different format and needs a different function to read/import them.